# Solve $(\frac{z+1}{z})^5 =1$ using fifth roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

$$(\frac{z+1}{z})^5=1$$
Show that its roots are $$-\frac{1}{2}(1+i\cot(\frac{kπ}{5})), k = 1,2,3,4$$
I need to use the five fifth roots of unit, with angles $0,\frac{π}{5}, \frac{2π}{5},\frac{3π}{5},\frac{4π}{5}$

I started by doing $$\frac{z+1}{z}=(\text{cis}(2πk))^{\frac{1}{5}}$$
$$z(1-\text{cis}(\frac{2πk}{5}))=-1$$
$$z=\frac{-1}{1-\text{cis}(\frac{2πk}{5})}$$
I am tempted to change the $1$ to cis form too, but that would eliminate the denominator and divide by $0$. How do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$-{1 \over 1 - e^{2\pi i \over 5}} = {e^{-{\pi i \over 5}} \over e^{\pi i \over 5} -e^{-{\pi i \over 5}}}$$
Recognize the denominator in terms of another function?

Comment: What have you done in the second step?

Comment: multiplied the numerator and denominator by $e^{-{\pi i \over 5}}$

Comment: It is obviously immensely helpful, but how did you come up with that? What was the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Well, there's a cotangent in the expression you are trying to show it is equal to, and so since $\cot = {\cos \over \sin}$, it makes sense to try to make the denominator into a sine.